# Okta Sign-in widget check if user is authenticated

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, okta

I am integrating the Sign-in widget into the music store example.
Using the widget I can sign in, and after successfull authentication I am redirected to the landing page. (using the code from the example page http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/okta_sign-in_widget.html#creating-an-html-file-with-the-widget-code

In the music store example, the Request.IsAuthenticated is true after login, but this isn't the case wen logging in using the widget.
How can I check if a user is signed in after he's authenticated using the sign-in widget?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to call `getUserInfo()` on the token

```js
oktaSignIn.authClient.token.getUserInfo().then(function(user) {
       console.log(user);
          }).catch(function(e){
            console.log(e);
          });
```

[You can also use the introspect endpoint to validate the token](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#introspect)